# "We'll move your old appliance to another room in your house, or haul it away for $20."

Tags: meaning

"We'll move your old appliance to another room in your house, or haul it away for $20."

Are they saying the $20 charge applies for moving or hauling away the appliance?  Or it only applies if it is hauled away?

Comment: It's ambiguous, perhaps deliberately, so you should just ask them.

Comment: It could  be either, but I would definitely interpret that as only hauling it away costs $20. You'd definitely want to ask to be clear.

Comment: Yes and that's a pretty-good example of why lawyers really do not like commas in legal documents.

Answer (score -1):

As it stands, the sentence is unambiguous, although I suspect that the writer didn't intend what they have actually written.

To apply the $20 definitively to either action, an additional comma is needed to make "or haul it away" parenthetical:

> We'll move your old appliance to another room in your house, or haul it away, for $20.

As it stands, the comma separates two alternatives. One of those is to haul it away for $20; the other is to move the appliance to another room. There is no mention of the cost of the moving service: it could be free (which would be a reasonable inference) or it could cost $200. Or even $20.

The sentence categorically states the alternatives, one of which has an explicit cost.

Comment: A better way to make it unambiguously apply to both would be to move the amount up front: “For $20, we’ll move your old appliance to another room in your house or haul it away”.

Comment: The question didn't ask for "a better way to make it unambiguous"; it asked about the ambiguity. And actually, it's not ambiguous, although it doesn't impart all the information that (presumably) it was intended to. In any case, whether moving the amount or adding a single comma is "better" is purely a matter of opinion.